# How do I revert back to default values in HTML/DOM after triggering an event(jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I go back and fro i.e switch to Celsius upon clicking the button, then reverting back to Fahrenheit when I click again? Surely it should not be this hard, but I am missing something here.

Here are the relevant codes:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ancient</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><span id="temp1">-40</span> &deg;<span class="units">F</span></h1>
    <p><span id="temp2">-28</span> &deg;<span class="units">F</span></p>
    <button>Show Celsius</button>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"
      integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA="
      crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script 
      src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
      integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" 
      crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script src="fahtocels.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    let $temp1 = Number($("#temp1").text()),
        $temp2 = Number($("#temp2").text()),
        $units = $(".units").text();

    function fahrToCels(F) {
        return ((5/9) * (F - 32)).toFixed(2);
    }

    $("button").on("click", function() {
        $(this).html("Show Fahrenheit")
        $("#temp1").html(fahrToCels($temp1));
        $("#temp2").html(fahrToCels($temp2));
        $(".units").html("C");
    });
});
```

Comment: Where is your function to convert celsius to fahrenheit?

Comment: @BrettGregson It's the one right after the variables declarations.

Comment: That's fahrenheit to celsius, not celsius to fahrenheit

Comment: @BrettGregson Oh sorry, I misread that. I have updated the code on my end. It's all good now.

Comment: Cool, glad you came right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is capable of **converting back and forth between celcius and faherenheit**.  What you were missing was a function to convert it back, along with a check to see what the current unit is.  This version fixes that.

```
$(function() {
    let $temp1 = Number($("#temp1").text()),
        $temp2 = Number($("#temp2").text()),
        $units = $(".units").text();

    function fahrToCels(F) {
        return ((5/9) * (F - 32)).toFixed(2);
    }

    function celsToFahr(C) {
        return (C * 9/5 + 32).toFixed(2);
    }

    $("button").on("click", function() {
        if ($(".units").html() === "C") {
            $(this).html("Show Celcius")
            $("#temp1").html(celsToFahr($temp1));
            $("#temp2").html(celsToFahr($temp2));
            $(".units").html("F");
        } else {
            $(this).html("Show Fahrenheit")
            $("#temp1").html(fahrToCels($temp1));
            $("#temp2").html(fahrToCels($temp2));
            $(".units").html("C");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thought there would be a another (read: shorter) way. It is not entirely accurate, though, 'cause when you convert to Celsius then back to Fahrenheit, you lose the initial values. I'll try tweaking it to get it to work correctly. Regardless, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You want to have a sort of `toggle` functionality. I'd store the current unit within a button like this `<button id="js-hook" data-current="F">Unit Toggle</button>`.

Then on my click event listener run a `switch` on it like so:

```
$("#js-hook").click(function() {

  var currentUnit = $(this).attr("data-current");
  switch (currentUnit) {

    case "F":
      // calculate celsius then swap data value
      $(this).attr("data-current", "C");
      break;
    case "C":
      // calculate fahrenheit then swap data value
      $(this).attr("data-current", "F");

  }

});
```

Basically, every time you click the button, it reads the current metric and if it's currently `C`, we run our calculation and then set it to `F`, etc.

**JSBIN DEMO: http://jsbin.com/kafewikece/edit?html,js,console,output**

Comment: Thank you. Will definitely try it out.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to store these values in variables. They can be attached directly to the window for a quick POC, but the best practice is to enclose your behavior in a closure to maintain the integrity of the data.

something like:

```
// IIFE to create a closure
// $ will be window.jQuery
// sample will be window.sample
// undefined will be an object that is undefined (so you can compare it like null without doing typeof
(function ($, sample, undefined) {
    // add a namespace for the behavior in this closure
    var ns = sample.namespace || (sample.namespace = {});

    var settings = {
        setting: "defaultvalue"
    };

    // attach a named function expersson to the namespace
    // outside of this closure this will be available at window.sample.namespace.handleButtonClick();
    ns.handleButtonClick = function(){
        console.log(settings.setting);
    };

    // document ready
    $(function() {
        // code in here will have access to the ns alias and the settings object
    });

})(window.jQuery, window.sample || (window.sample = {}));
// passing in jQuery and something to attach to the window (window.sample will either be the existing instance of window.sample or a new object)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.